# How can I conditionally format chart labels in COGNOS 10.2.2?

Tags: charts, formatting, label, cognos

I have a 100% stacked bar chart in a COGNOS 10.2.2 report with three series. I want one series to display data labels in black, and the other two in white. There does not seem to be a conditional formatting option for the data labels. How can I make this happen?

Comment: There are many options in a Cognos chart. Can you provide a screenshot to show us exactly what you want to conditionally format?

Comment: Unfortunately, I am working on a secure server and cannot provide a screenshot on a public server.

Comment: Can you not mock-up an example that contains no real data?